# Orientation issue in webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am opening an url in my universal application in a web view with orientation enabled, in portrait orientation first time the website load properly but when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape its working properly but when come back from landscape to portrait the website's contents of bottom dose not load, its working properly in iPod's, and iPhone both orientation properly but only iPad portrait orientation the bottom content dose not load when I change orientation, and when I open this url in my iPad safari browser all things working properly, please help me someone.

Thanks in Advance,
Rameshu